# Strategy to run Firebase transactions sequentially (NodeJS client)

Tags: node.js, firebase

Is this a "proper" way to run Firebase transactions that depend on each other sequentially using the NodeJS client:

```
ref.child('relationships/main').child(accountID).transaction(function(data) {
    return r;
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
        if (error) {}
        else if (!committed) {}
        else {
            runNextTransaction();
        }
    });
```

Originally I was going to put runNextTransaction() in the core function because transactions first run locally, but wouldn't that then hold open the original transaction until the last transaction in the chain is complete, possibly causing issues? (Also I need good data for the next step so I would have to handle collisions before moving on.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transactions run asynchronously, so kicking off the next transaction from within the first one would work, but it may not do what you want. Transactions functions can be run more than one time, and you likely don't want to initiate multiple secondary transactions in that case. What you have looks like the right way to do serial transactions. If you're interested in making things a little cleaner, especially if you're going to chain multiple transactions, consider looking into Promises.